# Google script : Copy and paste value from one sheet to new sheet when row is being added in certain column (different sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm encountering error when a row is being added in certain sheet(Sheet12) then function will be triggered to move a sheet("CustomerDatabase") to new sheet("Final").

Here is the google script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  if (sheetName == 'Sheet12' && column == 1)
    var prevNumRows = sheetName.getLastRow();
  if (row > prevNumRows) {
    var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("CustomerDatabase");
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("B:J");
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Final");
    var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("A:I");
    destinationRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

I'm new to google script and not sure what is causing an error to the script. I would be appreciated if anyone could help to resolve this error.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I'm encountering error when a row is being added in certain sheet(Sheet12) then function will be triggered to move a sheet("CustomerDatabase") to new sheet("Final").`, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: By the way, in your script, `sheetName` is a string value. By this, an error occurs at `var prevNumRows = sheetName.getLastRow();`, because `getLastRow()` is the method of Class Sheet. Please be careful about this. And also, if you want to use `prevNumRows` as `getLastRow()` of "Sheet12", I'm worried that `row > prevNumRows` might be always `false`. If I misunderstood your script, I apologize for this. So, I would like to correctly understand your expected result.

Answer (score -1):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // replace with the name of the source sheet
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // replace with the name of the target sheet
  var columnToWatch = 3; // column to watch for new rows, starting from 1
  var valueToCopy = e.range.getValue();
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1);

  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == sourceSheet.getName() && e.range.getColumn() == columnToWatch) {
    targetRange.setValue(valueToCopy);
  }
}
```